# Why is $ g'(s)=\frac{\partial f(t,y+s(x-y))}{\partial x}(x-y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

> If $g$ is defined as $g(s)=f(t,y+s(x-y))$ why is $\displaystyle g'(s)=\frac{\partial f(t,y+s(x-y))}{\partial x}(x-y)$

Does it not have to be $\displaystyle g'(s)=\frac{\partial f(t,y+s(x-y))}{\partial (y+s(x-y))}(x-y)$

What, if it was $f(s+t,y+s(x-y))$ instead of $f(t,y+s(x-y))$ ?

It is at the top right

http://oi62.tinypic.com/110fz7l.jpg

The book: Ordinary Differential Equations by Luis Barreira and Claudia Valls

Comment: Actually. I am confused to why the first statement is true. I seem to be missing something here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(t,x)$ depends on two variables: the first $t$ and the second $x$. The notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ means the derivative with respect the second variable. When finding
$$
\frac{d}{ds}f(t,y+s(x-y))
$$
we have by the chain rule
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{ds}f(t,y+s(x-y))&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \text{ first variable}}\frac{dt}{ds}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \text{ second variable}}\frac{d}{ds}(y+s(x-y))\\
&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,y+s(x-y))\,(x-y).
\end{align}$$

Comment: but $x$ in $\partial x$ is just the representative for the second variable, then it makes sense, otherwise they need not to be equal, BUT maybe the integral of them are equal, did you look at the picture I uploaded, thanks for your response

Comment: It is just a matter of notation. In some texts you will find $\partial_1u$ or $u_i$ for the derivative with respect to the $i$-th variable. That way there is no confusion about what is meant. Te integral has nothing to do with it.